# How shall I set up embedded Remote Desktop connection through two firewalls

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, firewall, wired-networking

I am trying to configure remote desktop to Target PC external network as shown in Image below.

The idea is to do a remote desktop connection from External Network to Buffer PC and then to take one more remote desktop connection from Buffer PC to Target PC.

If we keep only one defalut gateway, the connection to only that side is successful. If we configure two default gateways (which is inocorrect) still the connection to only one of either side is successful.

I have little background in networking. Could you please help me understand how shall I configure this so that we could take a remote desktop connection from External Network to Buffer PC and then through Buffer PC to Target PC?

[image: Basic Design]

Comment: Is the "first firewall" doing network address translation? If so, you don't need a second route, you need a port forward on it (and then connect via that firewall's address).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If we configure two default gateways (which is inocorrect) still the connection to only one of either side is successful.

In that case you need... *non-default* gateways. In other words, you need to define **routes** – where a "default" gateway is a route that matches *all* otherwise not matched destinations, in this case you need to create a more specific route on the "Buffer PC" that matches *only* 192.168.N.0/24 and specifies a gateway for that route.

(I assume it's 192.168, and I think it's safe to guess all your networks are /24's. Regardless, do not censor out information that does not need to be censored.)

Windows is *far* from being the best choice for a "buffer" PC, but it does have the `route.exe` command and the equivalent `New-NetRoute` PowerShell cmdlet for configuring custom IP routes, i.e. defining gateways for specific destinations. (Use `route -p` to have it add "persistent" routes.) There is no GUI configuration for this.

Comment: Thank you @u1686_grawity for the detail. I will try this out and confirm the results.